# SQL expression to decision tree

Tags: qgis, sql

I have an SQL expression with a lot of `CASE WHEN`. I'm trying to see if there is a simple way to take this expression, and turn it into a drawing decision tree.

This would be helpful to explain for external people the different decisions.